# Data frame with inverted date info

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe with two types os data format... ['Data Faturamento'] is "yyyy-dd-mm" and all the others are "yyyy-mm-dd", which brings an error while using np.busday_count().

"Data faturamento" is the only column with this format...

Whats the easist way to format it? I have tried this, and it's not working.

```
dataFaturamento = pd.to_datetime(baseFinal["Data Faturamento"],dayfirst=True).values.astype('datetime64[D]')
   
0        2022-08-01 14:04:00
1        2022-08-01 14:04:00
2        2022-08-01 10:24:00
3        2022-08-01 10:24:00
4        2022-08-01 10:23:00
                 ...        
185772   2022-06-24 09:44:00
185773   2022-06-24 09:43:00
185774   2022-06-24 09:43:00
185775   2022-06-24 10:30:00
185776   2022-06-24 10:30:00
Name: Data Faturamento, Length: 185777, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The right format I'd like to use is here:

```
0        2022-01-10
1        2022-01-13
2        2022-01-11
3        2022-01-11
4        2022-01-11
            ...    
185772   2022-06-24
185773   2022-06-24
185774   2022-06-24
185775   2022-06-24
185776   2022-06-24
Name: Data Entrega, Length: 185777, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: You'll have to coerce the values co-independently of each other. Can you provide a sample of the dataframe with both formats ?

Comment: Just updated the question with the other data frame column sample

Comment: This is actually pretty difficult, bordering on impossible unless there is some logic we can infer. Is there a logical break between the two formats? For example does the format change after month 3?

Comment: @LuizRibeiro *['Data Faturamento'] is "yyyy-dd-mm"* , means all the values in this column follows this format?

Comment: @Umar.H,@Naveed  That's it...  yyy-dd-mm in ['Data Faturamento']  and it's not supposed to change. I have data extracted from 6 months and it's the same format.

Comment: @LuizRibeiro, in the question, you posted this date for Data Fauramento  185772   2022-06-24 09:44:00, which is in yyyy-mm-dd format.  so, it seems this column has data in both formats.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, this what you expecting. For sorting the **Data Faturamento** column, you can use

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Data Faturamento',ascending=True)
```

After for getting only the date from Data Faturamento column, you can use which format you need to compute according to your case,

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data Faturamento'],format = '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S').dt.date
```

or

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data Faturamento'],format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.date
```

Hope this will help for you.